# https mixed content warning only on page reload in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, security, https, mixed-content

I'm working on a test site (not publicly accessible).

It has a valid certificate and when I visit a certain page it shows as secure in chrome...

When I refresh the same page, it shows the security info i icon.

On the security tab in dev tools it says there's mixed content (no other issues)

When I reload the page with the security tab enabled there are no mixed content issues.

The page always shows secure in Firefox.

Does anyone know what causes chrome to show the security info icon, only on reload, and not when the dev tools are open?

I've found a page on another website where this is happening...

https://www.volkswagen.co.uk/financeCalculator/generateDefaultCalculation?modelId=1997

1. If you go to that link ^^^

   - It shows secure
2. Hit refresh

   - It shows insecure
3. Open dev tools security tab

   - It says it's got mixed content
4. Refresh to get details of mixed content

   - Page shows as secure.

Comment: Are people seeing the same thing on Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VW page you linked to does serve its favicon over http which is the reason for Chrome showing the security info icon.

[image: Chrome showing mixed content warning]

Comment: Accepting for now... Will test and amend my actual page.  But it looks like this is the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a plugin/extension on Chrome that injects http links and messes with the overall result regarding mixed content.
To check this you can go to the network tab in developer tools and search links that start with `http://`

Comment: I think this could be the right area, I can't replicate this issue on incognito now.  Disabling all extensions doesn't solve the error in Chrome non incognito. I'll try disabling all extensions, then restarting Chrome to see if this resolves the issue.

Comment: One of the issues it that this isn't reproducible when the developer tools is open, which makes it near impossible to debug.  Thanks for taking the time to add an answer Bogdan.